# I am trying to create a new virtual machine in bluemix, getting an error about network name not existing

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I am attempting to create a new virtual machine in Bluemix. I got the email lettng me know that the service has been enabled, but then I try to create the new virtual machine instance, I get an error about a missing network name. The network name dialog on the previous screen of the wizard had no values, so I could not select one.

Do I need to do something to create the network as a pre-requisite to creating the virtual machine?

Comment: If the issue is resolved could you accept the answer?

Comment: The issue is now solved. Networks are available to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved. There were some issues with keystone but things should be fixed now. Please let us know if you are still having issues.